# Monitor when a CMT transaction is started, committed, reused, ... in JBoss 6.X

Tags: jboss, transactions, jboss6.x

I'm looking for a way to visualize, or to see, when JTA transactions are created, reused, committed or rollbacked.
I tried the TRACE logging in com.arjuna.ats, but this logging is really overmuch.

I have 3 EJB's, all of them CMT managed, but I actually want to debug the transaction statements.
Any tools for this? Or other log entries?

Thanks!

Comment: It's a little bit easier to read if you read the server log like this: $ tail -f server.log | grep "BasicAction"

Answer (score 2):

Try using the [Narayana Transaction Analyser](http://planet.jboss.org/post/narayana_transaction_analyser_1_0_0_alpha1). 
Also see the following tutorial which is about [Monitoring JBoss Transactions](http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-configuration/monitoring-transactions-with-jboss-wildfly-as) 
Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, the transaction analyser seems interesting, although our product is still running on JDK 6. The transaction analyser seems to be requiring JDK 7. I'm not able to start the EAR file in JBoss 6.1.0. Final

Comment: Ah, I just read you can only run it on WildFly 8.x, so it's not possible to run it on our application server :-( ...